# After which event in Hitman: Codename 47 does this event take place?

Tags: hitman-2016

In the prologue missions (Freeform Training and The Final Test) in *Hitman (2016)* (which also have been featured in *Hitman 2* later), we see **47** appear at a secret **ICA** recruitment facility. Here Diana greets him and while talking she asks him what felt like taking lives. At which he replies:

> Random... disordered...

In *Hitman: Codename 47*, we never knew what happens between **47** escaping the asylum and working for **ICA**. Instead, we immediately saw him doing assassinations for them. So was **47** already killing people before joining **ICA**? Was he working for someone else? Or it was just the asylum staffs before he escaped?